# How to get the values from an api call into a ViewModel in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

So the code is a mixture of both Java and Kotlin. The API call is made and is sent to this model class

```
public class ApiMediaMaxCntInfo {
    @SerializedName("ImageCount")
    private int imageCount;

    @SerializedName("VideoCount")
    private int videoCount;

    public int getImageCount() { return imageCount; }

    public int getVideoCount() { return videoCount; }

}
```

It is suppose to receive two `int` values.

It gets sent to a UI data layer and those calls are initialized into the model.

It goes up through the repo, into the VM, into the Fragment. It seems like the API call is made in the Fragment, but I'm not too sure. Here's the code

Fun in the VM

```
 fun doCheckMediaMaxCount(): LiveData<Event<UiResponse<UiMediaMaxCount>>>{
        return RxHandleUtil.handleEventPublisherWithContentChange({
            surveySiteSurveyRepository.getMediaMaxCountUC(getApplication())
        }, { maxMediaCountInfo ->
            UiMediaMaxCount(
                maxMediaCountInfo.imageCount,
                maxMediaCountInfo.videoCount)
        })
    }
```

Here's the Fun in The Fragment

```
 private fun handleMaxMediaCountCheck() {
        processViewModel.doCheckMediaMaxCount().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver { response->
            handleRxResponse(response, object : OnResponseListener<UiMediaMaxCount>(){

                override fun onServerFailResponse(message: String?) {
                    message?.let { it1 -> showError(it1) }
                }

                override fun onInvalidResponse(message: String?) {
                    message?.let { it1 -> showError (it1)  }
                }

                override fun onSuccessResponse(data: UiMediaMaxCount?, message: String?) {
                    data?.let {
                        maxPicCnt = data.imageCount
                        maxVideoCnt = data.videoCount
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

As you can see, the values are coming from the UiMediaMaxCount, but when I make the call inside the View Model, it's not getting the value from the API (which is 3 in total. 2 Images, 1 Video).

The UIMediaMaxCount

```
data class UiMediaMaxCount(
    val imageCount: Int = 0,
    val videoCount: Int = 0
)
```

How I set up the values in the VM

```
private val imageCnt = UiMediaMaxCount().imageCount
    private val videoCnt = UiMediaMaxCount().videoCount
    private val dataOverflow2 = imageCnt + videoCnt
```

Any suggestions is appreciated, Thanks.

P.S. Here's the api response code

```
public class MaxMediaCountInfo {
    private int imageCount;

    private int videoCount;

    public MaxMediaCountInfo(@NonNull ApiMediaMaxCntInfo apiMediaMaxCntInfo) {
        imageCount = apiMediaMaxCntInfo.getImageCount();
        videoCount = apiMediaMaxCntInfo.getVideoCount();
    }

    public MaxMediaCountInfo() {
    
    }

    public int getImageCount() { return imageCount; }

    public int getVideoCount() { return videoCount; }

    
    
}
```

and the Repo code

```
override fun getMediaMaxCountUC(context: Context): Flowable<UiResponse<MaxMediaCountInfo>> {
    return getUserInfoFromStorage(context).flatMap { userInfo ->
        siteSurveyRemoteResource.getMediaMaxCount(userInfo.userCredential.token)
            .map { apiResponse ->
                val cntInfo = MaxMediaCountInfo(apiResponse.data[0])
                UiResponseFactory.getSuccessUiResponse(cntInfo, apiResponse.message)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you getting in result then ? 0, 0 ? Issue could be in your surveySiteSurveyRepository

Comment: Not sure. I'm assuming its more than 3 in total because of where I am using it. It is going passed 3.

Comment: You need to share more data then to analyze the issue, share your api response and repository class please.

Comment: Added the additional code (response and repo)

Comment: put a log or debug and tell me what you get values for this `apiResponse.data[0]` Better provide the entire values for this `apiResponse`

Comment: The `apiRespone` does return 2 and 1 for `imageCount` and `videoCount` respectfully.

Comment: Can you pease share the response you get from network ? can b in json format

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the equivalent POJO class of the API response you get is `ApiMediaMaxCntInfo`. It has two public getter methods and both `imageCount` and `videoCount` is private. So to access the values, you should call the getter methods and that is the only way.

So I think the call `maxMediaCountInfo.imageCount` is not correct. You should do it like this `maxMediaCountInfo.getImageCount()`.

Comment: The values do show up in the Fragment, but not in the view model. That fun is used to carry the values up to the fragment.